# How to get the LDAP OU of the user using node / passport?

Tags: node.js, passport.js, ldap-query

I'm working on LDAP authentication / authorization flow in my Node.js app, and need to retrieve the OU to which a given user belongs.

The following code get me the user, but when I inspect it, I do not see the OU:

```
var express = require('express'),
    passport = require('passport'),
    bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
    LdapStrategy = require('passport-ldapauth');

var opts = {
    server: {
        url: 'ldap://ldap.forumsys.com:389',             // Host + port
        bindDn: 'cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com',  // user DN
        bindCredentials: 'password',                     // Password
        searchBase: 'dc=example,dc=com',                 // Base DN
        searchFilter: '(uid={{username}})'
    }
};

var app = express();

passport.use(new LdapStrategy(opts, function(user, done){
    done(null, user);
}));

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
app.use(passport.initialize());

app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('ldapauth', {session: false}), function(req, res) {
    var ou = req.user.distinguishedName;
    res.send({status: 'Hello ' + req.user.uid});
});

app.listen(8998);
```

Given this code, what is the proper way to retrieve the OU?

Comment: Can you try adding `includeRaw: true` to the opts.server. This should fetch the raw data received. That hopefully would have the OU as well. I don't have a LDAP server to test and verify

Comment: Thanks Tarun. I have tried, but OU/group is not in the raw either.

Comment: There is another property you can try `groupSearchAttributes: ["all"]`. See if that helps

Comment: still about the same. got cn, dn, but no OU

Comment: Try changing all to ou. Actually needs debugging the source but I don't have access to a AD server

Comment: still - same output. The test ldap serverI'm using is forumsys. The "login" command I'm using for testing - curl -d username=tesla -d passwordst:8998/login

Answer (score 1):

The issue is the LDAP server, not your code. If run against an Active Directory server, your code will return the full path to the object.

I tested both against your online test server, and an AD server.

From the comments on the [forumsys](https://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) site, it seems that to get the OU you would need to query the OU objects themselves for members. I don't think this is standard in most LDAP setups.

> In this particular LDAP setup, the OUs are of type groupOfUniqueNames.
>   Because of this, membership in the group is determined by the
>   uniqueMember attributes that are present with each OU. To determine a
>   user’s OU membership, you would have to scan each of the OUs and find
>   a uniqueMember attribute containing the DN of the user you are looking
>   for.
>
> If you wish to look at this for yourself, please use Apache Directory
>   Studio and the information provided above to review the setup.

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve OU using member, memberof or distinguishedName search criteria supplying a specific user's DN in the query which should resolve this.

From your code:

User's DN is:

```
cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com
```

So, your search filter can be, memeber=user's DN or distinguishedName=user's DN:

```
searchFilter: '(member = {{cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com}})'

searchFilter: '(distingushedName = {{cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com}})'
```

Don't have an LDAP AD to test the code but this should work.